# Blazorise check not letting click on it and disabled not working

Tags: blazorise

I'm using an inline three checkbox components in a form, my problem is that when they are not disabled I click on them and they are not checked. Also the disabled is not working .
Any idea?

This is my code

```
<Form @onsubmit="HandleSubmit">
 <InlineField>
        <Check TValue="bool" id="@Checkbox1" Inline="true" @bind-Checked="Person.Check1" disabled=@(Action == ActionType.View)>Check 1</Check>
        <Check TValue="bool" id="@Checkbox2" Inline="true" @bind-Checked="Person.Check2" disabled=@(Action == ActionType.View)>Check 2</Check>
        <Check TValue="bool" id="@Checkbox3" Inline="true" @bind-Checked="Person.Check3" disabled=@(Action == ActionType.View)>Check 3</Check>
    </InlineField>
</Form>
```

Thanks in advance. Guillermo.

Answer (score 0):

Change from `id` to `ElementId` and change from `disabled` to `Disabled`.